# Clone activity dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-activity, clone

I'm creating an application with a rather dynamic UI that allows users to add/change the positions of its views and layouts dynamically. If the user decides that current UI design satisfies him he would be able to save all views(`buttons/labels/switches/etc.`) of the activity into a list of "saved" activities. Is there a possible way to clone an activity or at least save the positions of all views and layouts? I saw that views have functions

> .getX()

and

> getY()`

but as far as I understood it is only within a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this is built into Android.  You could do it by generating the data you need and writing it to a file, but you'll have to do it completely on your own.

Comment: Could i at least clone the layout of the activity?

Comment: No, there's no build in functionality to do that.  Again you could write something that does it, but you're starting from scratch.